# IIS 10 Disable SSLv3 for only one site

Tags: iis, iis-10

We have a server running IIS 10 with multiple sites all currently using SSL 3.0. Is it possible to disable SSL 3.0 (to enable TLS) on only one of the sites without affecting the others?

Thanks

Comment: Simply impossible. It is all or nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying this out, I can confirm that this is not possible.

To disable SSL, registry changes must be made to the machine's cryptography stack settings which are shared across all sites.